# Is there any way to tell what time it is?

Tags: ghost-recon-wildlands

The reason I ask is because at nighttime, it's pitch black.  I don't like using night vision very much as it can be too bright if you accidentally look at lights.

Can you check what time it is in the game? I'd rather start and do certain missions in the light of day so that I'm not restricted to just night vision.

Comment: But clearing bases at night everyone is asleep, making it very simple to shoot them in their beds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, apparently there is a way to see the in-game time, though it is relatively obscured. From [this Reddit PSA](https://www.reddit.com/r/Wildlands/comments/5w7jq7/psa_there_is_an_in_game_clock/):

> I found today that there is a clock. If you look through your binoculars on the right hand side of the screen in the middle there is a clock right above what province you are in.

Comment: Though I don't like having to open my binoculars to check the time, it appears to be the only way :/

Answer (score 3):

Also if you just view the map (I suppose this may be a new feature), it states what in-game time it is under your player's info on the top right.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very SIMPLE way to see the time today (July 31 2018). I imagine it is part of one of the updates. NOW just hit your Map key, normally "M" key, and in the upper right corner, below your name and the "Notifications Center" you will see your game time.

Comment: This appears to be the same answer given by Asinine over a year ago.